# Update Managed Metadata column with Workflow on Document Library

Tags: managed-metadata

I am trying to make a update to a Managed Metadata column on a Document Library, i have drop downs that will bring the value that will update the Managed Metadata column,

Can you please point me in the correct direction, workflow that i currently have runs and completes successfully but update to the Managed Metadata column does not happen.

Comment: you want to update a managed metadata field value using SharePoint designer workflow

Comment: Yes, correct. SharePoint Designer workflow.

Comment: it is not clear why does application need to use dropdown instead of managed metadata field. Pls clarify.

Comment: Hi Alok,

I have 4 Cascading drop downloads that are linked to an approver, Country, Department their information needs to be used to update the Management Metadata columns

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the right format for the metadata like this

> ID;#name|guid

When it comes to set a managed metadata column with multiple values, you can need to format the value like this:

> ID;#Termlabel|GUID;#ID;#Termlabel|GUID